How to change file path in BAT file based on the current user?
I am new to batch scripting so please offer constructive advice on how to approach the task.
I have a bat file to run some Python code similar to this:
@echo off
set /P State=                         Select State:
set /P Year=                          Select Year:

"C:\Users\MYNUMBER\OneDrive - Company\filepath\python.exe" "C:\Users\MYNUMBER\OneDrive - Company\filepath\tst.py" %State% %Year% 
pause

I want different users at my organization to be able to run this file without any issue, but currently the path specifies my User number (called MYNUMBER).
What is the best way to make this bat file runnable for anyone in the company?

Change MYNUMBER to %username%

Your system has some environment variables which can be used to generalize you batchfile. Change the python line so it uses one of the variables and then this variable will be replaced at runtime by the correct value. The variable %userprofile% will give the value "C:\Users\MYNUMBER". The variable %onedrive% will give the value "C:\Users\MYNUMBER\OneDrive - Company"

Just be aware, that you could also use %OneDriveCommercial% for this, although %OneDrive%, should always be correct for the currently logged-in user. So simply change it to either "%OneDrive%\filepath\python.exe" "%OneDrive%\filepath\tst.py" %State% %Year%, or "%OneDriveCommercial%\filepath\python.exe" "%OneDriveCommercial%\filepath\tst.py" %State% %Year%. I should also say that you should be very careful using unchecked and unquoted user input like that.
